# Keyboard shortcut to make something "code"

Tags: support, markdown, code, keyboard-shortcuts

If I type in Hello and then highlight it and press ctrl+i it will change it to *hello* (thus making it look like this *hello*).

Is there a `ctrl+i` or `ctrl+b` equivalent to make something code?

I want to type in MyClass and select it and press a magic key combo and then have it be `MyClass` (so it will look like this `MyClass`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have co-opted the control-k for that (instead of letting it mean kill like it does in a proper editor). Which you could learn by reading the tool tip for the 010101010101 button.

Comment: OK, I feel dumb that it was on the tool tip.

Comment: @Vaccano: Don't. I only noticed on the tooltip when I was answering this question. I know it because it conflicts with my emacs reflexes.

Comment: that last sentence does come off as pretty harsh. Also, "the 010101010101 button"? I only get a "101 / 010" button! Lucky stiff....

Comment: ::cast about desperately for some way to excuse rudeness or at least divert attention::

Answer (score 4):

**There is more than one way to do it**

This also works:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

(Numeric keypad, the add key.)

Tested with Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: `ctrl + shift + =` (where `shift + =` is equivalent to `+`) also works (so no requirement for a numpad)

Comment: @MarkElliot `ctrl + shift + =`  — I wasn't able to figure this out on Firefox 100. The numpad method works, yours activates Firefox's zoom function.